# Inverse trigonometric substitution for integrals

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve this integral by inverse trigonometric substitution.
$$
\int_{0}^1{\sqrt{4kx-k^2x^2}dx}
$$ where k is an arbitrary constant.
I completed the square to get this:$$
\int_{0}^1\sqrt{2^2-(kx-2)^2}dx
$$
Then, I substituted $kx-2=2\sin \theta$ into the integral to obtain:
$$
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\sin^{-1}(\frac{k-2}{2})}2\cos{\theta}\frac{2}{k}\cos\theta d\theta \\ 
=\frac{2}{k}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\sin^{-1}(\frac{k-2}{2})}2\cos^2{\theta}+1-1d\theta \\ 
=\frac{1}{k}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\sin^{-1}(\frac{k-2}{2})}2\cos(2\theta)+2d\theta \\
=\frac{1}{k}(\sin(2\theta)+2\theta)|_{-\pi/2}^{\sin^{-1}(\frac{k-2}{2})}
$$
However, when I tried to check by substituting $k=2$, I get$$
\int_{0}^1{\sqrt{4\cdot2\cdot x-2^2x^2}dx}=1.333333754
$$ but my answer returns$$
\frac{1}{k}(\sin(2\theta)+2\theta)|_{-\pi/2}^{-\sin^{-1}(\frac{k-2}{2})}=1.570796327$$
I am not sure where I have gone wrong with my substitution. I thought I merely left out a 2 multiple but that was not the case. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Why is there no $k$ in the boundaries?

Comment: Are you sure this is a correct integral? If $k$ is arbitrary, you could get something uncomfortable in the case k>4. Or k<0

Comment: I apologise for that, I have edited in the boundaries. The lower bound remained the same because $x=0$. There was no information provided for k in the question, I could only assume it to be properly behaving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to substitute $kx-2=2\sin\theta$. For the lower boundary, $x=0$, we have
$$-2=2\sin\theta\Rightarrow\theta=-\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
And for $x=1$, we have
$$k-2=2\sin\theta\Rightarrow\theta=\arcsin\left(\frac{k}{2}-1\right).$$

Comment: Yes, I did this, and when I checked k=2, I got the answer above of 1.57 instead of 1.33. I am not sure where I went wrong now.

Comment: I tried to do that, but I ended up with this:
$$
\frac{1}{k}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\arcsin(\frac{k}{2}-1)}{2\cos(2\theta)+2 d\theta}=1.5708
$$
Note: Sorry about that, I accidentally hit enter instead of shift+enter. This is when k=2.

Comment: I can't see the formula.

Comment: Sorry for the ping, but I just needed to notify you that I updated my comment with the formula.

Comment: That's correct. I put the original integral in a computer and it gave me for $k=2$, that the integral is $\pi/2$, so $1.570796...$

Comment: However, when I used a TI-84 to directly evaluate the original pre-substitution integral, I am returned 1.333333754. So I am very confused.

Comment: Did you choose radians and not degree?

Comment: I really am sorry for wasting your time. It seems that a calculator reset solved the issue. I got $\pi/2$ with the original now. Thank you very much for your time and help, I really appreciate it.